# Is there anyway to get the path of a VBScript (.vbs) while it is running?

Tags: vbscript

I have a script.vbs that can be anywhere on a clients PC and it needs to create a directory relative to its location.   Is there a way for the executing .vbs to know where it is running?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found it.

**WScript.ScriptFullName**

strScriptPath = Left(WScript.ScriptFullName,InStrRev(WScript.ScriptFullName,"\"))